# Webpack rebuilds even if there's no changed files in watch mode

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm want to use webpack in watch mode (or with a dev server), but for some reason webpack rebuilds even if there's no changed files. I can't even imagine the reasons for this behavior, since the webpack doesn't say what exactly triggers the build.

```js
class WatchRunPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap('WatchRun', (comp) => {
      if (comp.modifiedFiles) {
        const changedFiles = Array.from(comp.modifiedFiles, (file) => `\n  ${file}`).join('');
        console.log('===============================');
        console.log('FILES CHANGED:', changedFiles);
        console.log('===============================');
      }
    });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new WatchRunPlugin(),
    // ...
  ],
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 500,
    poll: 20000,
    ignored: ['**/static', '**/node_modules'],
  },
};
```

And here's the output:

```
===============================
FILES CHANGED: 
  /mnt/c/Users/Yoskutik/project/DesktopAccountDisabledPage.tsx
===============================
// Build info...
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 8875 ms
===============================
FILES CHANGED: 
===============================
// Build info...
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 5100 ms
```

It builds once with the changed file, but for some reason after this build, it does it again with no changed files.

Could you suggest any ideas how to debug it?

Comment: have you find out what is causing the issue ?

Comment: No, but it was something with my Windows environment. After I migrated to MacOS, the problem was solved. But I didn't investigate the real reason